# passing table name as parameter in postgresql

Tags: plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.1, stored-functions

I have below table and records i have to pass the table names (`"LandXML_QCC_ParcelMarks"`, `"LandXML_QCC_ParcelInformation"`) as a input parameters (`tblparcelmarks`, `tblparcelinfo`) to the below function.
how can i use the this table name parameter in my query in below function. I tried but it is not working.

```sql
create table "LandXML_QCC_ParcelMarks"("DPID" TEXT,"From" TEXT,"Name" Text);

insert into "LandXML_QCC_ParcelMarks" values('1','ram','kumar');

create table "LandXML_QCC_ParcelInformation"("DPID" TEXT,"Pntref" Text);

insert into "LandXML_QCC_ParcelInformation" values('1','ram');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getparcelnonparcelfinal(planid text, tblparcelmarks text, tblparcelinfo text)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare
    tblmark RECORD;
    parCount integer;
    parNonCount integer;
    totalParNonCount text;
    tblCou integer;
begin
    parCount = 0;
    parNonCount = 0;
    FOR tblmark IN (SELECT "From", "Name" FROM tblParcelMarks where "DPID" = planid) LOOP
        SELECT COUNT(*) into tblCou FROM tblParcelInfo where "DPID" = PlanID and ("Pntref" like '%' || tblMark."From" || ',' || CAST(tblMark."Name" As text) || '%' or "Pntref" like '%' || CAST(tblMark."Name" As text) || ',' || tblMark."From" || '%');
        IF tblCou > 0 THEN
            parCount = parCount + 1;
        ELSE
            parNonCount = parNonCount + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    totalParNonCount = CAST(parCount As text) || ',' || CAST(parNonCount As text);
    return totalParNonCount;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Please help it is very urgent.They create table name with in double quotes.

Comment: I guess you need dynamic commands and the plpgsql variant of ```EXECUTE```: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: i tried but it is showing some error message.so please do the needful

Comment: Some errormessage? What is it exactly? And what is the code you have tried?

Comment: i will post new thread.First I tried passing table name as parameter to FOR LOOP it is showing error operator does not exist: text = integer